Best Practices for Handling Navigation in Flutter SDUI: Framework Navigation vs. Custom Navigation Stack
I am developing an SDUI using Flutter. I have one major question related to navigation. This question isn't specific to any particular framework, but since I am developing with Flutter, I thought it would be useful to mention Flutter.
How should navigation be handled? Should we use the framework-level navigation system, or should we implement our own navigation system using a stack?
Framework Navigation: If we use a framework-level navigation system, we can only use pre-defined routes like (/homepage, /profile, /login, etc.) that are specified during build generation. If I want to display a new route without an app release, this might not be possible.
Own Navigation: If we create our own navigation system, we would need to manage many aspects similar to what Flutter, KMM, or Jetpack Compose handle. We would need to implement proper stack navigation. In this case, everything would be rendered on the same page. For example, if I render the homepage and then navigate to the profile page, we would push the profile page JSON over the homepage or we define few general pages like /homepage, /profile etc.
Please find this example.
Own Navigation SDUI Demo
Currently, we are able to generate UI from the server using JSON, and for navigation, we are using Flutter's navigation system.
I need your help with this. How should I move forward?

GoRouter package is all you need.
go_router
A declarative routing package for Flutter that uses the Router API to provide a convenient, url-based API for navigating between different screens. You can define URL patterns, navigate using a URL, handle deep links, and a number of other navigation-related scenarios.
Link:
https://pub.dev/packages/go_router
